# Problem with using Google Font to produce beamer PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

thank you for any friendly comments in advance.

I use xelatex engine to generate PDF of Beamer, the work environment is R Markdown and I specify the YAML as below:

```
---
title: Presentation for Research Planning - Literature Review and Academic Writing
subtitle: 
author: 
institute:
#titlegraphic: 
fontsize: 11pt
output:
 beamer_presentation:
    template: C:\Users\Desktop\R Files\svm-latex-beamer.tex
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex # pdflatex also works here
    dev: cairo_pdf # I typically comment this out  if latex_engine: pdflatex
    slide_level: 3
make149: true
mainfont: "Titillium Web"  # Try out some font options if xelatex
titlefont: "Palatino Linotype" # Try out some font options if xelatex
---
```

The template I use is downloaded from http://svmiller.com/blog/2019/08/r-markdown-template-beamer-presentations/

`mainfont: "Titillium Web"` This is what I downloaded from Google and installed.

`titlefont: "Palatino Linotype"` This is already in my system, so I don't need to install it. And this font works.

After installment and before I post here, I have checked that the new font is in my local system. I have updated my Tinytex package and restarted my computer as well. But still doesn't work, errors come up as:

> ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Titillium Web" cannot be found.
>
> ! kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Titillium Web', contains ' '
>
> error: LaTeX failed to compile presentation_sample.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See presentation_sample.log for more info.

I have no idea, but I really want to add some cool fonts to my slides! BTW, my R version is:

> sessionInfo()
>
> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Hi, I have just added it. Besides the YAML and template, I do not write any codes in my .Rmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the font is correctly installed, your document should work fine. However you can work around the installation problem by placing `TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf` into the same folder as your `.rmd` file and then call it via

```
mainfont: "TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf"  # Try out some font options if xelatex
```

Comment: Thank you bt unfortunately doesnt work for my case... it shows: ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

Comment: @FinleyHuaxin Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Hi, yes my template tex is just the same as https://github.com/svmiller/svm-r-markdown-templates/blob/master/svm-latex-beamer.tex

Comment: @FinleyHuaxin No, not the template. The intermediate .tex file that is generated during the conversion from rmd to pdf

Comment: (btw I would make a big detour around this template, it loads a ton of unnecessary packages, some even several times. Most are already loaded by beamer - this should really be cleaned up)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have just uploaded it to my dropbox, here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw98tjdehp56njs/presentation_sample.tex?dl=0

Comment: Yes, I tried to delete some unnecessary sentences but I am quite new to latex, I have to be really cautious when I adjust these codes.

Comment: @FinleyHuaxin The problem is the `\usepackage{fontspec}` within your document body. Can you check your rmd file if you see this somewhere?

Comment: omg, yes!!!!!!!! i just deleted it and now my font works!!!! thanks a tooooonnnnnn!!!!!!!